# Boost module's "Cache every page except the listed pages" option

Tags: caching

I use Boost 7.x.
I couldn't use "Cache every page except the listed pages" option.
If i leave the textarea (of exclusion of some pages) everything works well.

In "/admin/config/system/boost" it is written like this:

> Specify pages by using their paths. Enter one path per line. The '*' character is a wildcard. Example paths are `blog` for the blog page and `blog/*` for every personal blog. `<front>` is the front page.

When I add the allowing lines, Boost breaks to cache files.

- content/my-alias-1
- content/my-alias-2

Am I using the wrong format for writing those lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this question is moldy old bread, but I wanted to answer for future searchers.

If a page has been cached by boost and then you exclude it, the cache will need to expire or be manually cleared before the exception will be used.

This is probably why you were still seeing the cached page when you added an excluded page.